# I can't start my Struts 2 project at work. I always get the following error messages:

Tags: struts

> Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/home/murali/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/struts-2-demo/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:54:100
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>   Caused by: Action class [org.apache.struts2.TestAction] not found - action - file:/home/murali/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/struts-2-demo/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:54:100
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:480)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:424)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:541)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:290)
>       at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:239)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
>       ... 18 more

Comment: Is something wrong @struts.xml:54

Comment: `Caused by: Action class [org.apache.struts2.TestAction] not found - action` did you check if you have this action class?

Comment: Agreed; it looks as though your action class is not being deployed.